# Obtaining an elasticsearch query from Kibana

Tags: python, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I want to convert the following kibbana elasticsearch query for a query in the `elasticsearch.count(index=indices, body=query)`.

Goal is to get a count for given timestamp(last 24 hours), cluster and integer_field > 0.

- timestamp : date type
- cluster: string
- integer_field : long (values
  are mostly greater whole numbers)

The query being (obtained from Kibana)

```
curl -XGET 'some-url:9200/logstash-2015.07.03,logstash-2015.07.02/_search?pretty' -d '{
  "facets": {
    "0": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "@timestamp",
        "interval": "10m"
      },
      "global": true,
      "facet_filter": {
        "fquery": {
          "query": {
            "filtered": {
              "query": {
                "query_string": {
                  "query": "*"
                }
              },
              "filter": {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "range": {
                        "@timestamp": {
                          "from": 1435840604940,
                          "to": 1435927004940
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "fquery": {
                        "query": {
                          "query_string": {
                            "query": "integer_field:(>0)"
                          }
                        },
                        "_cache": true
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "fquery": {
                        "query": {
                          "query_string": {
                            "query": "cluster:(\"YYY\")"
                          }
                        },
                        "_cache": true
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}'
```

I have written queries for other cases. It is only this case , where I am stuck. Help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query that you are looking for is simpler than the one that Kibana is forced to autogenerate. Generally speaking, when pulling them from Kibana, you want to look for the "filtered" query portion. From there, you can remove wildcard conditions.

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool" : {
          "must" : [
            {
              "term" : {
                "cluster" : "YYYY"
              }
            },
            {
              "range" : {
                "integer_field" : {
                  "gt" : 0
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "range" : {
                "@timestamp" : {
                  "gt" : "now - 24h"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The "cluster" `term` filter is the only one that is possibly not "valid" for your use. `term` filters are *exact* matches for the indexed values, so if it's not literally "YYYY" (e.g., "yyyy"), then it won't match. It's possible that you want the `{ "term": { ... } }` to be:

```
{
  "fquery" : {
    "query" : {
      "match" : {
        "cluster" : "YYYY"
      }
    }
  }
}
```